# Properties of a scheme with a closed morphism to a normal crossing divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

All schemes here are noetherian, separated and of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $D=V_+(xy)\subset \mathbb{P}^2=Proj(\mathbb{C}[x,y,z])$ be the normal crossing divisor comming from the coordiante axes in $\mathbb{A}^2$. Denote the crossing point in $D$ by $p$.

Assume there is a scheme $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ which admits a surjective and projective morphism to $D$, that is $f: X\rightarrow D$, wih the property that $f^{-1}(p)$ is not empty and connected.

What can we say about $X$?

Let us write $X=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ a decomposition in connected components. Then what is $f(X_i)$? Since $f$ is closed and $X_i$ is closed and connected, the same is true for $f(X_i)$. But connected and closed subsets of $D$ are either a closed point, one of the lines, or $D$. Furthermore there is a unique component containig $f^{-1}(p)$ since the fiber is connected, let us assume this component is $X_1$.

Is it possible that $X_1=f^{-1}(p)$? I think not, since $p$ lies on both lines in $D$ and hence $f$ can map $X\backslash X_1$ only to a finite set of points. But then $f$ cannot be surjective. I think with the same reasoning one can see that $f(X_1)$ cannot be one of the lines. So it remains the possibility $f(X_1)=D$, that is $f$ is already surjective on $X_1$.

This seems somehow strange to me, $f$ maps one component surjectively to $D$ and the rest to a finite set of points? Or can it happen that $X=X_1$, i.e. that $X$ is connected? Maybe I am making some dumb mistake here?

Comment: I think you're correct. Some connected component dominates the $x$-axis, and by properness its image contains p. Same for the $y$-axis, and since you insist that $f^{-1}(p)$ be connected, those connected components are actually the same one.